pine script - modifying right side of rectangle doesn't work
this pine script code suppose to draw a rectangle everyday at 00:00 and at 01:00 change the right side position of rectangle to the bar index at 1:00 . but modifying the right side only work immediately after creating the box not even one bar after. so my question is how can i do this?
//@version=5
indicator("rectangle", overlay=false)

box box = na
int startindex=0
startindex := (hour== 0 and minute == 0) ? bar_index : startindex[1]

if(hour==0 and minute==0)    
    box := box.new(startindex,
                    2,
                    bar_index, 
                    4,
                    bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 95), 
                    border_width=2,
                    border_color = color.black,
                    border_style=line.style_solid,
                    text = "the rectangle",
                    text_color = color.white,
                    text_size = size.normal)

if(hour==1 and minute == 0)
    box.set_right(box,bar_index)


the second if statement triggered but modification of box doesn't work.

You need to use the var keyword on your box declaration. Otherwise, you will lose your reference.
var box box = na


